# Every time I change networks, DNS cache has the wrong IP. How to fix automatically every time?

Tags: networking, dns, intranet

My company's employees website can be accessed:

- from the outside world via its IP address 1.2.3.4 or name `employees.corp.com`
- from inside the company's network via its IP address 192.168.1.2 or name `employees.corp.com`

Problem: After commuting from home, accessing the website `employees.corp.com` from inside the company often fails.

- When it fails, if I run `ping employees.corp.com` it says `64 bytes from w91284.telco.com (1.2.3.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=2.08 ms`.
- I am the only person with this problem. All other employees browse `employees.corp.com` all the time, inside and outside, with no problem. I am also the only one using Linux (Ubuntu 2018.04 installed from scratch but I had the same problem with 2016.04).

I have found two workarounds for when that happens:

- Workaround A: Edit the URL to replace `employees.corp.com` with `192.168.1.2`
- Workaround B: Run `sudo service network-manager restart`

Both of these workarounds fix the problem momentarily, but none is satisfying as they waste time every day. What would be a permanent solution?

Disabling or shortening DNS cache would make the whole Internet a bit slower to access so I would prefer if it is limited to this particular domain. I am open to completely different solutions too.

Comment: I agree and removed the flag... however I don't see how to partially clear the DNS cache. To my knowledge, dnsmasq does not support it (see this discussion http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2014q1/008264.html)

Comment: Does it help to run `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` instead of restarting network manager?

Comment: Because you suspend your laptop when traveling. One solution would be a resume hook that automatically runs `sudo  service network-manager restart`.

Comment: @SebastianStark: Would this be a permanent solution? Or a slightly better workaround that I would still be forced to use every single day?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Sounds like a great idea!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul it's less disruptive at least. It's not a proposal for a permanent solution (yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This systemd script restarts Network Manager when resuming from suspend.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

MYNAME=$0

restart_network() {
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_network BEGIN'
    systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
    /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_network END'
}

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'case=[' ${1}' ]'
case "${1}/${2}" in
    hibernate|suspend|pre*)
      ;;
    resume|thaw|post*)
      restart_network;;
esac
```

You'll need to create this script, called `network-reset`, with sudo powers and save it into the directory `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`. Then mark it executable using:

```
chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/network-reset
```

The `logger` commands above allow you to audit results by running `journalctl` or by looking in `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

I was mostly satisfied with WinEunuuchs2Unix' solution but somehow it was still failing sometimes for whatever reason so I had to restart the network very often, often 4 times during the same sitting at my company desk.

I finally ended up setting my WiFi connection to always use both DNS addresses:

[image]

It probably results in slower connection sometimes, but at least I can connect to the company website reliably.